# How do I make this code list the top twenty movies with help of the rating?

Tags: c#

Any ideas how or what to add to make this code list the top 20 Movies based on the item.rating? In C# because we are doing a school project where we are building a Movie database, so I would appreciate if someone also could give me some tip as I am Learning to program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;

namespace MovieCollection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Movie> movieColletion = GetMovieCollection();   
        }

        static List<Movie> GetMovieCollection()
        {
            List<Movie> list = new List<Movie>();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/moviecollection.xml");

            XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/MovieCollection/Movies");
            list.OrderBy(x => "/moviecollection.xml").ToList();
            list.OrderBy(x => GetMovieCollection()).ToList();

            foreach(XmlNode row in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                Movie item = new Movie();

                item.id = Int32.Parse(row.SelectSingleNode("Id").InnerText);
                item.name = row.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
                item.rating = Double.Parse(row.SelectSingleNode("Rating").InnerText.Replace(".", ","));
                item.votes = Int32.Parse(row.SelectSingleNode("Votes").InnerText);  
                item.year = Int32.Parse(row.SelectSingleNode("Year").InnerText);                

                list.Add(item);
                System.Console.WriteLine(item.name + " " + item.rating);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 3):

```
// assuming higher ratings are better:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Movie> movieColletion = GetMovieCollection();
    List<Movie> top20Movies = movieCollection
        .OrderByDescending(m => m.rating)
        .Take(20)
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetMovieCollection` method is returning a `List<T>`.  Lists have methods for sorting and extracting ranges of data.  Sort the list, then extract the first 20 elements.

Sorry if I'm being vague, normally I would help in more detail, but you admitted its for a school project, so I'm going to leave some thing up to question.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2